# Unable to find the control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page. In that aspx page I have 2 user control. In my second user control, I want to find the control for the first user control.

ASPX File

```
 <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                   <uc1:ControlA ID="Page1" runat="server" />
                   <uc2:ControlB ID="Page2" runat="server" />
              </td>
          </tr>
 </table>
```

In my 2nd user control,

```
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/ControlA.ascx" %>

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControlA gridData = (ControlA)this.Page.FindControl("Page1");
        }
```

Here, I get the gridData as null only. How can i get the object of my first user control. First User Control 1 is loaded, then it comes in 2nd user control. SO first should be loaded. I debugged and checked it.

Comment: Don't do that. You are hard-wiring both usercontrols which is against the nature of them(reusability). The correct way in such cases is to provide a custom event in `ControlB` which is raised and can be handled by the page, the controller of both. Then the page can use properties or methods in `ControlA` to do what you want. But if both controls depend on each other so much it's better probably to use a single control.

Comment: I don't think user control is rendered as such, it should be a div. Also their ids are subject to be prepended with the container I'd.

Comment: @Rohit since this is server-side code, using `ID` and not `ClientID` should be fine, and the markup that is generated is also not a concern. It's more likely that either this code is nested in another container, or the control doesn't exist in the page's controls collection yet.